# Plotly express choropleth map not showing correctly

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. I have a shapefile with county borders for all of Canada and I want to show the population density of the counties in PEI (eventually all of Canada, but using PEI as a starting point). I extract the PEI data needed which includes the CDUID (id number for counties) and the geometry of each county.

[Link to Stat Can website where the data is from](https://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/alternative_alternatif.cfm?l=eng&dispext=zip&teng=lcd_000b16a_e.zip&k=%20%20%20%2032295&loc=http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/2016/lcd_000b16a_e.zip)

This is what my code looks like.

```
    import geopandas as gpd
    import pandas as pd
    import plotly.express as px
    import json

    counties = gpd.read_file('lcd_000b16a_e.shp') #Reading all county data
    counties_PE = counties.loc[counties['PRUID'] == '11'] #Selecting PEI county data

    counties_PE.to_file('counties_PE.geojson', driver='GeoJSON') #SHP to GeoJSON
    counties_PE_geojson = json.load(open('counties_PE.geojson', 'r'))

    PE_popdensity = pd.read_csv('County Population Density.csv') #Read pop density file
    PE_popdensity['CDUID'] = PE_popdensity['CDUID'].astype(str) #Force CDUID to be a str

    fig = px.choropleth(PE_merged, 
        locations='CDUID', 
        featureidkey='properties.CDUID', 
        geojson=counties_PE_geojson, 
        color='Pop_density', 
        height=600
        )

     fig.update_geos(fitbounds='locations', visible=False)

     fig.show()
```

Below is the table for the Population density data along with the CDUID number.

| CDUID | Pop_density |
| --- | --- |
| 1101 | 10.9 |
| 1102 | 45.2 |
| 1103 | 23.0 |

Image of what I get when plotting it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLFwq.png)

And zooming in a bit shows this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ9Gp.png)

I'm relatively new to plotly, so maybe I'm making a mistake, but if someone would be able to point where I'm going wrong out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is `PE_merged`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the map is not displayed is that the coordinate system of the geometry used is not in a format that can be handled by plotly. So convert it to EPSP:4326. I corrected it to the data frame name in the question and got the map.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import json

counties = gpd.read_file('./lcd_000b16a_e/lcd_000b16a_e.shp') #Reading all county data
counties = counties.to_crs(4326) # convert to CRS:4326
counties_PE = counties.loc[counties['PRUID'] == '11'] #Selecting PEI county data

counties_PE.to_file('counties_PE.geojson', driver='GeoJSON') #SHP to GeoJSON
counties_PE_geojson = json.load(open('counties_PE.geojson', 'r'))

import io

data = '''
CDUID Pop_density
1101 10.9
1102 45.2
1103 23.0
'''

PE_popdensity = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
PE_popdensity['CDUID'] = PE_popdensity['CDUID'].astype(str) #Force CDUID to be a str

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth(PE_popdensity, 
        locations='CDUID', 
        featureidkey='properties.CDUID', 
        geojson=counties_PE_geojson, 
        color='Pop_density', 
        height=600
        )

fig.update_geos(fitbounds='locations', visible=False)

fig.show()
```

[image]